# Can't Start Apache and DB server Easyphp-devserver-17

Tags: wordpress, easyphp

I can't start Apache and database server through the Dashboard, i got this error msg :

[image]

[image: line 18 line 23]

Sorry i'm a php newbie, I'm on windows 7 and Easyphp 17
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What's line 18 of `index.php` look like?

Comment: follow these steps to fix the error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381872/4097509

Answer (score 0):

The code is the same as the default index.php file.

I believe that the undefined offset is happening because the HTTP and DB servers are not running.

Have you tried exiting/killing EasyPHP, then running it as administrator by right-clicking on the icon and choosing "Run as Administrator"?  On my 64-bit Windows 10 system it will not load Apache or MySQL unless I do that.  It worked the same when I tried on Windows 7 as well.